# it seems there is already a binary at /usr/local/bin/dmtracedump'

Tags: adb, homebrew

I ran into this problem when I tried to install android-platform-tools in MacOS

but the errors are keep showing up. I really appreciate for your help.

```
 % brew install android-platform-tools
==> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/e8b2b4cbe47c728c1e54c5f
Already downloaded: /Users/uni/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/b936bd1102a99be17a4fe2c04600e55535b473a99db318639bf685bc67e8dcc4--e8b2b4cbe47c728c1e54c5f524440b52d4e1a33c.platform-tools_r31.0.3-darwin.zip
==> Installing Cask android-platform-tools
==> Linking Binary 'sload_f2fs' to '/usr/local/bin/sload_f2fs'
==> Unlinking Binary '/usr/local/bin/sload_f2fs'
==> Purging files for version 31.0.3,e8b2b4cbe47c728c1e54c5f524440b52d4e1a33c of
Error: It seems there is already a Binary at '/usr/local/bin/dmtracedump'.
```

Comment: Have you tried first running `brew uninstall android-platform-tools`